# low voltage radio frequency amplifier

Tags: amplifier, rf, low-power, low-voltage

Is it possible to build an RF transmitter final amplifier that can be powered by a single lemon as a battery? (maybe 0.9 Vdc at 1 mA, with suitable electrodes, when fresh)

Desired operating frequency is somewhere in the range of high MF (1 MHz, Part 15) to HF (29 MHz with a U.S amateur license), gain of at least 6 dB over input drive signal, and output to a wire antenna.

If so, what kind of active component (BJT, FET, or IC, silicon or germanium, etc.), and type of circuit should one look into to work under this low voltage, low power and frequency requirement.

The purpose might be to provide a compelling visual demonstration of low voltage low power operation, so any manufactured battery or an adjustable 1 Amp supply won't work nearly as well as a lemon.

Comment: Are you using the amplifier to transmit or receive?

Comment: Transmit.  Maybe WSPR or CW. I've already had a few -8 dBm WSPR signals spotted 1k miles away.  Want to try even lower with a sub-mW powered final amp.

Comment: Why the lemon? Do you realize that that the lemon is only the electrolyte part of a lemon battery? An apple or potato will work as well. More important are the electrodes. But anyway, real batteries are cheap and provide more power for your money. And sure, such an RF amplifier can be made (start with a common emitter) but it will probably be unable to deliver any usable power.

Comment: The lemon can provide a nice visual demonstration of how little power is required for long distance RF communication. Much more interesting to kids than looking at some meter on a 25 A power supply.  Perhaps 2 lemons in series is required for a lemon battery sufficient for actual RF transmit?

Comment: Why was this question closed?  What requirement is missing?  It seems very specific to me.

Answer (score 4):

A common emitter amplifier made using a Bipolar Transistor (BJT) only needs 0.6V~0.7V to function, but with only a 0.9V supply you won't get much voltage swing on the output.

Also with only 1mA available the output impedance of the amplifier would need to be several hundred ohms minimum, so you are not going to get much power out of it.  You don't have enough voltage to make a class AB amplifier output stage (you would need something greater than 1.4V)

There are some very low voltage MOSFETS such as the BSH105 (0.45V threshold).
https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BSH105.pdf

Texas Instruments makes an OP-AMP LMV951 that can operate on as little as 0.9V.
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmv951.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-digikeymode-df-pf-null-wwe&ts=1607313906248

The gain bandwidth product is only 2.7MHz so its really only suitable for use up to 100s of kHz.

Comment: You could go back to Germanium to lower the Vbe required!

Comment: Germanium?  So something like a 2n404 common emitter configuration with a transformer coupled output?